# How to know when Rsyslog has read all lines in a file, and have read 100% of a file

Tags: logging, syslog, logfiles

I have to pull log files, static files. Let's imagine I have 100 events (100 lines) in a file. Rsyslog has to forward those logs to a server. Once Rsyslog has read the last line, I want to shutdown the container where Rsyslog is running.

Is there a way to know when RSyslog has read the entire file, and thus to know if can shutdown the container?

Thank  you very much

Answer (score 0):

There does not seem to be any built-in way to know that rsyslogd has reached end-of-file for an `imfile` module file.

A simple way would be to poll the appropriate open file descriptor of the rsyslogd process to find the current read position, and compare that with the size of the file. `lsof` can list this information for a process or a file, or you can just read file `/proc/P/fdinfo/N` where P is the appropriate pid and N the file descriptor.  Of course, this does not mean the read data has been sent yet, so you would then need to wait a bit.

Alternatively, within rsyslog you can configure the `omprog` module to be given all the same lines that are being sent to the server, and have the module pass them on to a program that counts these lines and compares that with the count of lines it must have first have read from the static logfile.

Or you could, before starting rsyslogd, append a special marker line to the end of the logfile, and match that line within the rsyslog config, again using `omprog` to run a program that would signal the shutdown instead of sending it onwards.

There is also an `impstats` module that can provide statistics on total lines read or written, but it does not seem to apply to `imfile`. However, you might be able to use it on the output module you are using. As I have not used it, I'm not sure how it might help.

Comment: thank you very much for the ideas!